# How do I configure a wildcard DNS record correctly in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to configure a DNS server for `domain.com`. I want to configure a wildcard DNS record to resolve `any-subdomain.domain.com` to a single IP address (172.16.1.3).  In my DNS server I have the following records in my forward zone:

[image: DNS Records]

This somewhat works, except that when I run `nslookup www.domain.com` I get this response:

```
Server: winsrv.domain.com
Address: 172.16.1.2

Name: www.domain.com.domain.com
Address: 172.16.1.3
```

I believe the DNS server is thinking that the entire `www.domain.com` string is a subdomain of `domain.com`.

How do I get the DNS server to return the correct line: `Name: www.domain.com`

Comment: Is `domain.com` in this example an Active Directory domain as well? And if so, is this DNS server an AD DNS server?

Comment: Nope, no AD in use. Just a fresh Windows Server 2012 with updates and DNS installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I suspect is happening but can't prove it on my own systems since I don't want to stick a wildcard record on my DNS servers.

> This somewhat works, except that when I run nslookup www.domain.com I
>   get this response:

```
Server: winsrv.domain.com
Address: 172.16.1.2

Name: www.domain.com.domain.com
Address: 172.16.1.3
```

This is because your nslookup query is technically an unqualified name.

You can test this by doing an `nslookup www.domain.com.` (note the trailing period/dot at the end that "qualifies" it) and see if the return is valid now.

EDIT: yeah this seams to be the case...because your wildcard entry is invalidating the normal `NXDOMAIN` response nslookup normally returns in this case.  Since nslookup always appends the suffix if the lookup doesn't have the trailing period.

For instance, here's one on my computer:

```
> set debug=true
> www.yahoo.com
Server:  dc1.mdmarra.local
Address:  10.10.10.10

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        www.yahoo.com.mdmarra.local, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
```

Notice how it returned NXDOMAIN for www.yahoo.com.mdmarra.local.  It will then go on to query just www.yahoo.com using forwarders.  Since you have the wildcard entry it thinks your query is valid based on the wildcard.

Comment: Yep. Looks like you're right. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Why is your DNS server named dc1.MDMARRA.local?

Comment: Is MDMarra your alter ego? That would explain why I never see the two of you answer a question at the same time.

Comment: @joeqwerty :) just my way of obscuring the FQDN since I know how much he hates .local names.  But I'll be happy to swap points with him.

Comment: He may forgive you for using .local in this instance ;)